# how to put parameters on url in spring mvc result page?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a very simple spring mvc project:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/form.htm")
public class FormController {

    FormValidation formValidation;

    @Autowired
    public FormController(FormValidation formValidation) {
        this.formValidation = formValidation;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initForm(ModelMap model) {
        QueryForm queryForm = new QueryForm();
        model.addAttribute("queryForm", queryForm);
        return "queryForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForm(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("queryForm")QueryForm queryForm,
                             BindingResult result) {
               List<String> Result = query(queryForm);
            SuccessForm successForm = new SuccessForm();
            successForm.setId(queryForm.getId());
            model.addAttribute("successForm", successForm);
            return "successForm";

    }
    private List<String> query(QueryForm queryForm) {
    }
}
```

success.jsp:

```
<head>
    <title>deviceInfo display</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Id is ${successForm.Id}.</h1>
<br>
        <c:forEach var="info" items="${successForm.Info}" >
                <p style="font-size:120%"><c:out value="${info}" /></p>
                    <hr />
        </c:forEach>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

query.jsp:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <form class="form" id="queryForm" method="POST" command="queryForm">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Please fill in the form</legend>
            <p>
                <label for="Id" class="sr-only">Id</label>
                <input type="text" name="Id" id="Id" class="form-control" placeholder="Id">
            </p>
            <p>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in this way, the url of the success.jsp page is the same with the query.jsp :http://localhost:8080/project/form.htm. I need to add some parameters on the query.jsp, like: http://localhost:8080/project/form.htm?Id=xxx, so the success page can be sent to others with result existing, how can I do that? thanks.
spring mvc version: **2.5.6**

Answer (score 0):

You have to user model attribute like you have already done for `successForm` and `queryForm` objects rather than sending parameters at the end of the url. And you can access the model attributes via jsp tags like

```
<c:out value='${modelObject.attrProperty}' />
```

Example

```
<c:out value='${successForm.Id}' />  //for object's properties
<c:out value='${isUserValid}' />    //for boolean values
```

For List:

```
List<UserForm> userForms = LoadFromDB();
model.addAttribute("userForms", userForms);
```

JSTL to iterate the above list:

```
<c:forEach items="${userForms}" var="userForm">     
   // Do something
</c:forEach>
```

Or you can use RedirectAttributes like this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/someURL", method=GET)
public String yourMethod(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
{
   ...
   redirectAttributes.addAttribute("Id", "IdValue");
   redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashVal", flashValue);
   return "redirect:/successPage";  //redirects to the `successPage` with params
}
```

Comment: thanks, I can access the attributes in successForm, but how can I use them to  generate URL's parameter?